# Django QuerySet API check if is unique for this id

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

This is how my model looks like:

```
class Catalog(models.Model):
    global_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    short_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    version = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=models.Q(
                //
                CHECK IF VERSION IS UNIQUE FOR THIS PARTICULAR GLOBAL_ID
                //
                ),
                name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_unique_version",
            )
        ]
```

As you can see, I need to make sure that version models are unique for a particular global_id, I just don't know how. Help.

Comment: What is your django version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below allows you to set a unique constraint against the two fields.
Note for this to work the unique constraint is removed from the `global_id` field.

```py
class Catalog(models.Model):
    global_id = models.IntegerField(max_length=10)
    version = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['global_id', 'version'],
                name='unique_global_id_for_version'
            )
        ]
```

```
>>> Catalog.objects.create(global_id=80, version=80)
<Catalog: Catalog object (10)>
>>> Catalog.objects.create(global_id=90, version=80)
<Catalog: Catalog object (11)>
>>> Catalog.objects.create(global_id=80, version=80)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: ...
>>> Catalog.objects.create(global_id=80, version=90)
<Catalog: Catalog object (12)>
```

Above, when trying to create a Catalog with `global_id=80` it failed as it already existed for `version=80`, but later a Catalog with `global_id=80` was able to be created for a Catalog with `version=90`.

[The docs for this constraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint)

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.unique) you can use the "unique" option for django 3.1 :

> If True, this field must be unique throughout the table.
>
> This is enforced at the database level and by model validation. If you
> try to save a model with a duplicate value in a unique field, a
> django.db.IntegrityError will be raised by the model’s save() method.

Which would make your declaration like this :

`version = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)`